# Calculate $a^3+b^3$ knowing $a+b=1$ and $a^2+b^2=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b=1$ and $a^2+b^2=2$, calculate $a^3+b^3$.

I tried to solve it using the Binomial Theorem, but I found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: $a^3+b^3=\dfrac{5}{2}$

Answer (score 5):

Using $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ you can find $ab$. Then using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$ you can find $a^3+b^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We have $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+?$

$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$